# Is there a way to access an element in amultidimensional array using a variable to store the indexes

Tags: r, multidimensional-array

Let's say I have a matrix A with n rows and m columns. If I want to acess the element on the i'th row and j'th column I can access it as A[i,j].
I would like to know how I can save this i,j in a variable x so that I can get A[x] = A[i,j]. storing them in a vector won't help since A[i,j] != A[c(i,j)].
I would like to be able to do this for a higher dimensional array where I don't know the dimensions ahead of time because they depend on the data that is suploaded by the user.

thank you very much!

Edit

what I ended up doing:
If x is the vector representing the Indices I needed, the solution is A[matrix(x,nrow=1))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `cbind` or calculate the position.

```
A <- matrix(1:12, 3)
A[2,3]
#8
A[3,1]
#3

i <- c(2,3)
j <- c(3,1)

x <- cbind(i,j)
A[x]
#[1] 8 3

x <- i + (j-1)*dim(A)[1]
A[x]
#[1] 8 3
```

Comment: Thanks! this still doesn't quite work becuase I still have to explicitlty input 2,3 to the cbind function or the calculation. I want to receive the indeces as a vector and use them even for higher dimensions (say 5 or 10)

Comment: This works also for vectors and higher dimensions.